# How do I trigger Yuan Shao's victory at the Battle of Guandu on PS2?

Tags: romance-of-the-three-kingdoms-8

After many years, I've finally returned to the fantastic Romance of the Three Kingdoms VIII to complete all its events and just enjoy mucking about the Middle Kingdom as a Roman centurion/Parthian POW/Chinese warlord.

I absolutely can't get Yuan Shao's victory at Guandu to fire.

The [Event FAQ](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps2/914672-romance-of-the-three-kingdoms-viii/faqs/23838) on GameFAQs says the following:

> 17. THE BATTLE OF GUANDU (YUAN SHAO'S VICTORY)
>
> START IN SCENARIO: 200
>
> YOU CONTROL: Yuan Shao or any of his officers
>
> OTHER REQUIREMENTS: Yuan Shao controls the provinces of Ji, You, and Yu; the Yuan faction is larger than the Cao faction
>
> RESULT: The event occurs before 202. Yuan Shao celebrates his victory at the battle of Guandu. Yuan Shao's fame goes up and the loyalty of his officers goes up too.

Cao Cao's equivalent event fired just fine after conquest and after playing both sides and just moving Yuan Shao out of the way. Yuan Shao's event simply won't fire, despite holding those three provinces in four separate games now.

There *have* to be other triggers or something I'm not doing right. As I'm playing the PS2 version and this is a guide for the PC version - is there something I'm missing here? Does anyone have any idea what the trick is on PS2?