# Replacing the restored emperor

Tags: romance-of-the-three-kingdoms-8

Same deal as [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/364884/rot3k8-battle-of-guandu-event), I have a question about two of the events in Koei's *Romance of the Three Kingdoms VIII*.

In *Rot3K8*, there are [96 events](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps2/914672-romance-of-the-three-kingdoms-viii/faqs/23838) that you can unlock in different games. Some involve playing a particular character in a certain scenario, some have special triggers such as marrying a particular woman or having X amount of infamy. Two of the last three that I have to complete are [events 93 & 94](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps2/914672-romance-of-the-three-kingdoms-viii/faqs/23838). They involve:

1. The Han emperor being deposed, as historically was carried out by Cao Pi & in-game can be accomplished in four or five separate ways;
2. A player-character controlling 10+ prefectures including Luoyang, which leads to the discovery of the former emperor and allows the PC to pledge fealty to him; and
3. A player-character controlling 40+ prefectures, which leads to the former emperor abdicating to permit the PC's elevation to emperor.

There are two separate versions of this, depending on whether the PC is a member of the Liu family (and thus continuing the Han) or not (in which case a new dynasty is proclaimed).

So my questions:

## 1. Is there any scenario in the game where one faction has *already* rediscovered the emperor?

which would spare a player needing to go through the trouble of the first two stages, and

## 2. Is it possible to trigger both events in the same game?

or is it impossible to do the Liu-family and non-Liu-family versions in the same game by trading control of Luoyang or redeposing the emperor?

Comment: Please leave the ps2 tag. There may be different triggers for the PC version, which I couldn't care less about. I'm asking about the ps2 version of the game.

Comment: No need to tag with [ps2] as per the meta post, [Platform Tags are Useless](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4638/4797). Just include the platform info in the question body. "*There may be different triggers for the PC version, which I couldn't care less about.*" The FAQ guide you linked to states (emphasis mine): "The Romance of the Three Kingdoms 8 (**PC VERSION**)".

Comment: __And the FAQ isn't working__ for at least one of the events and possibly these. The linked discussion notes the policy is to include the platform when it's a platform-specific question. This is.

Comment: @Ily I believe you are misinterpreting that [meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4638/4797). You only include the platform tag if the issue is specific to the *platform*, not the game version/port on the platform. Include all game version/port-specific info on the *question body*, instead. Quoting the linked meta post's top-voted answer: "Questions about a specific version or port of that game should *not* be tagged based on the platform, but should instead make a note of the version in question **in the body of the question** when relevant."